# Нужна ли запятая после "при этом" и в других местах?

Tags: запятые

ЖК РФ, Статья 45:

> При этом при рассмотрении данного вопроса в отношении жилых помещений,
> предоставленных по договорам социального найма или по договорам найма
> жилых помещений жилищного фонда социального использования,
> представителями собственников признаются наниматели таких жилых
> помещений.

Мой вариант:

> При этом, при рассмотрении данного вопроса в отношении жилых помещений
> предоставленных по договорам социального найма или по договорам найма
> жилых помещений жилищного фонда социального использования,
> представителями собственников признаются наниматели таких жилых
> помещений.

Answer (score 1):

ЖК РФ Статья 45 даёт текст без ошибок.

[! После союза «при этом» запятая не ставится.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_642)

И ещё Вы пропустили запятую перед причастным оборотом *(предоставленных по договорам социального найма или по договорам найма жилых помещений жилищного фонда социального использования).*

Comment: А вот интересно, кто и когда назвал "при этом" союзом? Мелкие, местечковые справочники можно не считать. Я, например, перерыл всю академическую грамматику 1980 и в ней такого не нашел. Зато есть такие наречия как притом, потому, поэтому. И  предложно-падежные выражения:  из-за этого, вследиствие этого, благодаря этому, соответственно этому, итд.

Comment: Вот интересно, вам интересно узнать, кто назвал «при этом» союзом  или как надо правильно называть. Вы, вероятно, думаете, что это не союз, а доказать можете?

Comment: Вам, боюсь, не смогу доказать. Другим уже доказал

Comment: Кому именно доказали, можно узнать. Я тогда у них спрошу. Мне тоже интересно, союз это или нет.

Comment: Ну вот мне плюсик кто-то поставил, ему доказал, значит.

Comment: Логика у вас та еще. Он же не сказал, за что плюсик. Вероятно, ему тоже интересно. А я же спрашиваю, можно ли доказать, что это не союз.  А вы  обычно авторитеты себе ищете (кто сказал. когда сказал), но не истину. Могли бы и сами подумать, да с другими своими знаниями поделиться (со мной, например).

Comment: Я привел все доказательства. Имеющий уши да слышит.

Comment: Ладно, я думала вы действительно разбираетесь в теме, вопрос-то сам по себе интересный. Извините.