# Как определить вид сложного предложения и союзного средства в случае присоединительных отношений?

Tags: союзы, сложное-предложение

Присоединительные отношения возможны **для всех видов сложных предложений** (ССП, СПП, БСП). Обычно в этом случае мы используем **как союзы, так и союзные аналоги.**

Можно ли назвать **признаки**, по которым определяется  **вид предложения и союзного средства,** например, в приведенных ниже примерах? Чем **отличаются** союзы от союзных аналогов?

(1) Погоду на праздники обещают теплую, **об этом** уже говорили.

(2) Да, но дождь все-таки возможен, **о чем** говорили тоже, **да и** прогнозы не всегда сбываются.

(3) Про дождь я тоже слышал, **этого** я и боюсь.

(4) Погода часто меняется, **так что** лучше  всё предусмотреть.

(5) Да,  **и поэтому** мы решили взять палатку.

Comment: А в первом и третьем предложении союзов-то нет. А союзным аналогом называют наречие поэтому. Этот вопрос мы обсуждали на нашем форуме.

Comment: Серж, я не ставила перед собой такой задачи – в каждом предложении разместить по союзу. Это диалог, в котором использованы все виды сложных предложений, а также союзы и союзные аналоги. Пока у меня есть определенная точка зрения на то, как определить вид предложения и как  отличить союз от союзного аналога. Я надеюсь с вашей помощью уточнить свое понимание темы. Что касается "поэтому», то это союзный аналог в БСП, но в нашем случае он используется вместе с союзом И.

Comment: Соответственно,  я считаю, что предложение (5) –  это ССП, а союзное средство является составным: сочинительный союз И + наречие "поэтому". Наречие конкретизирует соединительный союз И,  добавляя  значение следствия. Ориентируюсь я на учебник Кустовой, где рассмотрены все виды сложных предложений и названы союзные средства.

Comment: А что опредялять-то? Спорным является только предложение 5.

Comment: Ну как вам сказать. Эта тема связана с комментарием "А вот интересно, кто и когда назвал "при этом" союзом?" 
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463882/Нужна-ли-запятая-после-при-этом-и-в-других-местах/463883#comment481011_463883 . Что тут спорного?  Союзные аналоги часто именуют союзами, превращая БСП в СПП.  Союзное слово "о чем", не всегда отличают от "об этом". Да и вид предложения  затрудняются определить (почитайте комментарии), считая это делом вкуса.

Comment: Ну да, про аналоги я знаю. Я говорю не про них. Речь о других ваших предложениях.

Comment: По отношению к сочинительным союзам (см. § 1683) семантически дифференцирующую функцию часто выполняют специальные конкретизаторы, т. е. слова и словосочетания, которые подключаются к союзу и уточняют его значение. В образовавшемся при участии конкретизатора союзном соединении происходит распределение функций между собственно союзом и элементом, уточняющим его значение.

Comment: Таковы соединения: и потому, и поэтому, и в результате, и оттого, и тем самым, и стало быть, и следовательно, и таким образом, и значит, и притом, и к тому же, и кроме того, и в то же время, и вместе с тем, и все-таки, и все же, и однако, и все равно, и несмотря на это, и напротив, и наоборот, и тем более; а потому, а значит, а все-таки, а в то же время, а вместе с тем, а ведь, а тем более, да ведь, но ведь, но зато, но только, но все же, или иначе. В некоторых случаях конкретизатор, подключаемый к простому союзу, становится компонентом составного союза (см. § 1676); а именно, а также.

Comment: Типичным способом конкретизации подчинительных союзов (см. § 1683) является их соединение с предложными сочетаниями, например: после того как, ввиду того что, несмотря на то что, вопреки тому что, не в пример тому как, подобно тому как; в результате такого соединения образуется составной союз; см. § 1678.

Comment: Sharon, ваше мнение тоже неошибочно. Здесь мнения разделились.

Comment: Серж, у меня нет своего мнения, но есть такое понимание вопроса.  Существует научная среда, где много всяких мнений (это вполне естественно), но мне это неинтересно.  Я уже сказала, что я выбираю определенную школу,  которая на данном этапе кажется мне законченной, цельной, непротиворечивой  и которая достаточно авторитетна, чтобы я могла на нее ссылаться при решении вопросов практического письма.  Современный учебник (не из прошлого века!), который уже не первый год используется в высшей школе, меня вполне устраивает.

Comment: А ссылки на множественность научных мнений  среди  обычных пользователей языка мне кажется удобной лазейкой для того, у кого нет достаточных базовых знаний предмета.

Comment: Ну что ж, каждый сам выбирает, к какой школе придерживаться. Лично меня союзный аналог вполне устраивает.

Answer (score 1):

> Иногда ограничения класса союзов кажется лишь данью традиции, а
> сво­бодное употребление этого понятия — проявлением широты взглядов и
> при­знаком непредвзятого подхода. В этом есть доля правды.
> **Действительно, строгое определение собственно союза никем не
> сформулировано.** Практи­чески вопрос часто решается тем, как то или
> иное слово себя зарекомендо­вало

http://www.labslsl.ru/?p=1521&page=3

> Следовательно, необходимо указать и те формальные основания, которые позволяют, как нам кажется, отличить «союзный эквивалент» (частицу, модальное слово) или служебное слово типа «скрепы» от собственно союза. **Таких оснований нам видится два.**

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, обязательно ознакомлюсь с этой информацией.

Comment: ... союз показан как особый класс, релевантным признаком которого является не только связующая функция, характерная для всех
аналогов союза, но и функция конструирующая (статьи «Союз и его функциональные аналоги» и «Об отличии союза от других связующих слов»)
Поройтесь в статьях этой авторши. Она собаку съела на союзах.

Comment: ...Две статьи в этом разделе книги посвящены описанию текстовых скреп,
в том числе и особых служебных образований, обозначенных термином
«скрепы-фразы». Текстовые скрепы рассматриваются автором как особый
функциональный класс служебных единиц....

Comment: Спасибо, начала читать, но  еще не все прочитала. Немного напрягает то, что статья не самая новая (1978 год). Грамматика развивается сейчас очень динамично, и вот у Кустовой союзы для каждого вида сложного предложения определяются весьма однозначно, то есть просто перечисляются, союзные аналоги перечисляются также. Как-то у нее нет сомнений по этому поводу.  Термина "скрепы" у нее вообще нет. А вы, может, попробуете назвать вид предложения и союзного средства хотя бы без обоснования, чисто по интуиции.

Comment: 1978 год мне тоже показался подозрительным, пока я не увидел её бэкргаунд: 1960-2020, куча авторитетных работ (в том числе АГ-1980) и всяких диссертаций. А в СССР всяко качественнее подходили к делу, чем сейчас.

Comment: Думаете, за сорок лет ничего не изменилось. У Кустовой издания 2005 года и другие издания (с 2013 года) отличаются прилично, я уже думаю, не купить ли мне книгу 2019 года. Там материал в комплексе дается, как единое описание современного синтаксиса, вот что у меня вызывает чувство доверия.

Comment: За 40 лет возможно изменились издания её трудов. Она же сама писала их и в 2015. Могла что-то отредактировать в поздних изданиях. На интуиции: скрепы это "значит, следовательно". Союзы "так что, да и". Союзные слова "о чем". Обстоятельства-союзные аналоги: "об этом, этого". В любом случае "союзного аналога" недостаточно. А "коррелят" ну такое... лучше пользоваться новым термином: скрепы. Хотя она сама в АГ писала коррелят, а не скрепа.

Comment: У меня нет "значит, следовательно".  Есть 5 предложений, назовите их вид. Союзы и союзное слово вы правильно назвали, все остальное считаем союзными аналогами.

Comment: Так союзные аналоги разные бывают. Это слишком общий термин.

Comment: Меня пока устраивает, но попробуйте не ошибиться, называя вид предложения.

Comment: Вид это дело вкуса, мне кажется. Можно считать и так и так. Я бы на свой вкус считал ссп, но думаю принято считать спп.

Comment: А вот здесь "никакого вкуса", всё очень строго.  Поэтому и с аналогами становится  яснее - что и где применяется.

Comment: Конечно, строго. В одной теории строго спп. В другой теории строго ссп. В обеих все очень строго. Но я понял, к чему вы клоните. Это типа ссп.

Comment: Кустова - это учебник для  филологических факультетов непрофильных вузов, специальность "русский язык и литература". Там, вероятно,  утвержденный министерством вариант, который рекомендован для студентов. А разные теории, дискуссии и т.д.  только в научной среде бывают.

Comment: Ой, ну учебник должен делать какой-то выбор между теориями, вот он и делает. Беда в том, что он не мотивирует его и не объясняет. Просто говорит вот так утверждено министерством. Среди каких вариантов утверждено, почему утверждено? Если хотите и дальше продолжать следовать за министерством, не понимая почему, то пожалуйста. Важна не истина, а понимание истины.

Comment: @Sharon, а что значит "...для филологических факультетов непрофильных вузов. Специальность"русский язык и литература". Разве есть разница, где изучаешь профильный предмет? В профильных вузах учебники другие?

Comment: Может быть, и другие, если Кустова указывает свою аудиторию как журналистика, педвузы, факультет иностранных языков. Вероятно, для филологов-лингвистов программа по синтаксису более сложная.

Comment: @Sharon а-а, спасибо. Понятно.

Comment: У нас, например, вообще не было каких-то определенных учебников по русскому синтаксису. Только лекции.

Answer (score 1):

**Окончание дискуссии в комментариях  и мой ответ на вопрос**

**К Хаосу нас зовете?** Нет, мы за вами не пойдем. Грамматика – наука точная, и чем она точнее, тем больше вызывает к себе доверия и уважения. Школы могут быть разные, но каждая должна иметь непротиворечивую и цельную теорию. Отбор  делается просто – это **проверка практикой**. «Истинная школа» позволяет решать практические задачи, а основная задача – эта выбор корректной грамматической формы для заданного содержания и четкое ее оформление (в том числе постановка знаков препинания в соответствии с Правилами).

**Классификация** сложных предложений изучается в школе довольно подробно – со схемами, с указанием всех структурных элементов. Попробуйте неправильно указать вид предложения – и вы получите соответствующую оценку ваших знаний.  Учебник Кустовой (с 2013 года)  – это курс лекций для студентов, где сохраняется **преемственность**  со школьной традицией, но при этом решаются и новые задачи. Это описание синтаксиса на более глубоком уровне с более точными определениями, позволяющими четко обозначить вид каждого предложения и расставить  знаки.

**Что касается истины**, то она, как известно, вещь относительная. Учитесь у математиков:  у них функции  имеют заданную область определения и изучаются в этой конкретной  области. И у них точная терминология, не позволяющая «растекаться мыслью по древу». Это дает  возможность избегать  «синкретизма», который я понимаю как неясность и неопределенность  при изучении чего-либо, когда незнание маскируется под разнообразие теорий, так что непонятно где и что.

Попробую ответить на свои вопросы, используя следующие **основные положения.**  Существует **три вида** сложных предложений. Для каждого  вида составлена  базовая структурная схема. Грамматическим значением сложного предложения являются смысловые отношения между его частями.  Основные средства связи – это союзы, союзные слова, опорные  и указательные слова (для БСП – интонация).

**Союзы**  делятся на сочинительные и подчинительные, имеется их перечень. По союзам определяется вид предложения.  Основная разница между ССП и СПП в том, что сочинительные союзы стоят между предложениями, а подчинительные союзы (как элемент подчинения) включены в придаточное предложение. В то же время смысловая независимость соблюдается только для однородных ССП, а в случае неоднородности  определенная зависимость между простыми предложениями существует.

**Союзные аналоги** и различного рода структурные элементы (наречия, частицы, модальные слова) уточняют смысловые отношения, но они не участвуют в построении базовой структурной схемы.  Как отличить союз от союзного аналога?  Четкого определения в книге нет (эта тема просто не рассматривается подробно), но можно предположить **следующее**. Союз входит **в классификацию**  (в перечень сочинительных и подчинительных союзов), так как он определяет вид предложения.  Он должен стоять  **на границе**  между простыми предложениями (хотя  для союзных слов возможна и другая позиция) и   должен быть **самостоятельным,** то есть не должен сочетаться с другими союзами.  А союзные аналоги и структурные элементы не соответствуют  этим требованиям.

(1) *Погоду на праздники обещают теплую, **об этом** уже говорили.* Это БСП, союза нет,  предложная форма местоимения указывает на первую часть предложения.

(2) *Да, но дождь все-таки возможен, **о чем** говорили тоже, **да и** прогнозы не всегда сбываются.*  Между двумя первыми предложениями подчинительная связь (придаточное присоединительное), союзное слово «о чем», падежная форма относительного местоимения «что». Далее сочинительная связь, присоединительный союз «да и»

(3) *Про дождь я тоже слышал, **этого** я и боюсь.* Это БСП, союза нет,  предложная форма местоимения указывает на первую часть предложения

(4) *Погода часто меняется, **так что** лучше всё предусмотреть*. СПП с придаточным следствия. Это единственный союз с этим значением.

(5) Да, **и поэтому** мы решили взять палатку. Это ССП, а союзное средство является составным: сочинительный союз И + наречие "поэтому". Наречие конкретизирует соединительный союз И, добавляя значение следствия.  «Поэтому» не является полноправным союзом, так как может соединяться с сочинительными союзами, а также занимать в предложении свободную позицию; этим оно отличается от союза «так что».

Comment: 1. Статей там целый ряд, а не одна. Вы начали только с 1978, а есть еще 2010 итд. 2. Типизация предложений однозначно привязана к типу средств их соединяющих(сочинительный союз или подчинительный союз итд). Если мы определили тип средства, то тип предложения следует автоматически(по хваленым схемам). Вопрос лишь в терминологии. Как назвать средство "и значит" итд. Типа одна школа говорит: если у нас в начале сочинительный союз значит средство сочинительное. Другая школа говорит: если в конце смысловое подчинение значит средство подчинительное. Вам интересна эта возня с терминами? мне пока нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. «Возню» с терминами начали вы, если вспомните, я же вежливо попросила вас объяснить, почему  «при этом» – это не союз. Но вы почему-то отказались.   А вот теперь, оказывается, вы все знаете, я вам ничего нового сказать не могу. Ладно, может быть, кому-то мой вопрос покажется интересным и полезным (тем, кто еще не всё знает так хорошо, как вы).